# Path overlapping

Tags: android, 2d, android-canvas

I'm making an application that draws the path you followed the GPS, for what will need to paint lines serve wide (paint with 40 of stroke), not the typical hairline, the problem is that I need to spend 2 times the same site or overlaps a part of the path on the other distinguished in some way. At first he used lines (canvas.drawline) to connect the dots and line out setAlpha translucent and you could tell when the lines overlap, but over the GPS data lines being so fat is not seen as a continuum, I've solved using Path, but that I lost the ability to get them still using dial setAlpha overlap, there is some property or Paint Path that escape me?